# How to do some operation post sign in while using devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I need to do some operation(logging, update database etc) post sign in while using devise irrespective of which controller it redirects to. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Warden's [`after_authentication` callback](https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/callbacks).

From Devise's README: *Devise is based on Warden, which is a general Rack authentication framework*.